# Is there a characterization of automorphisms of degree-$2$ affine plane curves over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ denote a (nonsingular, irreducible) affine plane curve over $\mathbb{R}$ given by the explicit equation

$$A : a_Ax^2+b_Axy+c_Ay^2+d_Ax+e_Ay+f_A$$

> **Question.** Is there an explicit description of the automorphisms of $A$ in the category of real affine varieties?

Comment: 1. Do you want it's automorphisms as an abstract variety or remembering the embedding in the plane? 2. How far short of your expectations does "compute discriminant, recognize what type of conic it is, remember automorphism group" fall?

Comment: @KReiser, isn't $(1)$ irrelevant? I thought the definition of a morphism $A \rightarrow A$ was a pair of polynomials $P,Q \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that the induced map $(P,Q) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ restricts to a function $A \rightarrow A$. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @KReiser, also $(2)$ sounds fine, but where can I find the automorphism groups computed explicitly? If I understand correctly, we just have to do this for $x^2-y^2=1$, $x^2+y^2 = 1$, and $y = x^2$ to get a complete solution, but I still don't know how to do it for those curves.

Answer (score 1):

We will compute the result for $\Bbb C$, and note that an automorphism of $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb R[x,y]/f$ is the same as an automorphism of $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C[x,y]/f$ with real coefficients. Over $\Bbb C$, there are exactly two affine plane conics up to isomorphism: $xy=1, y=x^2$. So it suffices to compute the automorphism groups of each of these curves and do some work translating things back to the reals.

One preliminary result that I'll use without proof: $Aut(k(x))= PSL(2,k)$ acting by Mobius transformations.

Case 1: $y=x^2$. The coordinate algebra is isomorphic to $\Bbb C[x]$ by writing $y=x^2$. Any automorphism of $k[x]$ extends to an automorphism of $k(x)$, and the automorphisms of $k(x)$ that preserve $k[x]$ are exactly the linear maps. So the automorphisms of $\Bbb C[x]$ are exactly the linear maps $x\mapsto ax+b$ with $a\neq 0$. In order for these automorphisms to restrict the correct way to our curve, we just need $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Case 2: $xy=1$. The coordinate algebra is isomorphic to $\Bbb C[x,x^{-1}]$, and any automorphism is determined by it's action on $x$. Again, any automorphism of $k[x,x^{-1}]$ extends to an automorphism of $k(x)$, and the automorphisms of $k(x)$ that preserve $k[x,x^{-1}]$ are $x\mapsto ax$ and $x\mapsto cx^{-1}$ for $a,c\neq 0$.

We need to do a little more work in case 2 to translate these automorphisms back to the land of the reals. In the case that our curve over $\Bbb R$ is a hyperbola, we can make the change of variables $x\mapsto (x-y),y\mapsto (x+y)$ to translate between $xy=1$ and $x^2-y^2=1$. Recognizing this coordinate change as a rotation and performing some algebra, we see that the symmetries of $x^2-y^2=1$ are all of the form $\begin{pmatrix} \pm \cosh(a) & \sinh(a) \\ \pm \sinh(a) & \cosh(a) \end{pmatrix}$ for $a\in [0,2\pi)$.

Similar logic with the change of variables $x\mapsto x-iy, y\mapsto x+iy$ shows that the automorphisms of $x^2+y^2=1$ are exactly the rotation matrices up to a reflection across any line through the origin, ie matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} \pm\cos(a) & -\sin(a) \\ \pm\sin(a) & \cos(a) \end{pmatrix}$.

I wouldn't be surprised if there were a shorter proof, but this is the clearest approach I could think of while writing.